# Tallest bubble tower induction proof

Tags: calculus, geometry, induction

A hemispherical bubble is placed on a spherical bubble of radius $1$. A smaller hemispherical bubble is then placed on the first one. This process is continued until $n$ chambers, including the sphere, are formed. (The figure shows the case $n = 4$.) Use mathematical induction to prove that the maximum height of any bubble tower with $n$ chambers is $1 + \sqrt{n}$.

[image]

---

I can find the relationship of the radii :$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(R_{n}) = R_{n+1}$$

**But, I still do not see how to use the inductive hypothesis to make a proof.**

---

Suppose $R$ is the radius of the $n$'th bubble and $x$ is the radius of the $(n+1)$'th bubble. And suppose $d$ is the height added when the $(n+1)$'th bubble is added to the top of the tower.

$$\sqrt{{R_n}^2 - {R_{n+1}}^2} + R_{n+1} - d = R_n$$

Let $d(x)$ take $R_{n+1}$ as the input, and outputs the added height to the tower, $d$.

$$d(x) = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} + x - R$$

$$d'(x) = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} + 1 = 0$$

$$\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} = x$$

$$R^2 - x^2 = x^2$$

$$R^2 = 2x^2$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R = x$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R_n = R_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the hypothesis is true for towers with upto $n$ bubbles. Now consider a tower with $n+1$ bubbles. The bottom bubble has a sphere of radius 1. Let $r$ be the radius of 2nd bubble. Then, from hypothesis, bubbles $2$ to $n+1$ can have a maximum height of $r\sqrt{n}$ starting from the center of bubble number $2$. So maximum height of all $n+1$ bubbles is $1+\sqrt{1-r^2}+r\sqrt{n}$. First order condition for maxima is $r/\sqrt{1-r^2}=\sqrt{n}$ which yields $r^2=n/(n+1)$. Substituting this value of $r$, the maximum height of $n+1$ bubbles is $1+\sqrt{n+1}$.

Comment: How do you get $r\sqrt{n}$ from the hypothesis? That is the part that I am really confused about.

Comment: When the lowest bubble has a radius of $1$, the height of tower from bottom is $1+\sqrt{n}$. The height of the center of bottom bubble is $1$ so the height of the tower from the center of the bottom bubble is $1+\sqrt{n}-1=\sqrt{n}$. If the raduis of the bottom bubble is $r$ rather than $1$, this height is scaled by $r$ to get $r\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I think I see it, when I draw out what you say I can see the tower from $(Center)_1$ to $(Top)_n$ = $\sqrt{n}$. But then knowing that it is scaled by $r$ seems like a leap of faith, but it also seems right, somehow. I am not sure how you saw that connection, but great work.

Comment: @Leonardo Thanks. The scaling argument works because what matters for maximum height is the ratio of radii of different bubbles. If lowest bubble's radius is doubled, all other radii canbe doubled too.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have checked that 1 + sqrt(n) is true for the n = 1 case. Now you can use the fact that 1 + sqrt(n) is true for the n case to show that for the n + 1 case the maximum height is 1 + sqrt(n + 1)

Comment: I know how the induction part works, the question is how do I use the inductive hypothesis to show the $n+1$ case = $1 + \sqrt{n+1}$? It is not obvious to me.